# Java Conversion from byte[] to char[]

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer, java-security, charbuffer

I have wrote a simple snippet in which I try to convert (maybe) a byte array in char array e vice versa.
There are a lot of examples on the Net but this is for me the simplest way to do it.
I need to use array and not strings because its content is a **password** field to manage.

So I ask you, is this snippet correct?

```
private static char[] fromByteToCharArrayConverter(byte[] byteArray){
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);
    clearArray(byteArray);
    CharBuffer charBuffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").decode(buffer);

    char[] charArray = new char[charBuffer.remaining()];
    charBuffer.get(charArray);  

    return charArray;
}

private static byte[] fromCharToByteArray(char[] charArray){
    CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(charArray);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(charBuffer);

    byte[] byteArray = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(byteArray);

    return byteArray;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work for (at least) the following reason:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray);  // Wrap the array
clearArray(byteArray);  // Clear the array -> ByteBuffer cleared too
```

Comment: Ok Thanks. Now I'have deleted the second row. Now it could be workly? In your opinion using this way can I retrieve password for the Login phase?

Comment: I have to try later. Thanks for the moment.